# Const function in class can change the member value?

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

In the code below, why function SymmetricAxis can change x and y in p3? 
I think that const function will not allowed to change member's value. But it does, so I am confused.
Besides, if I change p3 to const CPoint p3, the compiler do not allow me to do this. But if p3 is not const, the program can change the member in p3.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

class CPoint
{
private:
    double x; 
    double y; 
public:
    CPoint(double xx = 0, double yy = 0) : x(xx), y(yy) {};
    double Distance(CPoint p) const;  
    double Distance0() const;         
    CPoint SymmetricAxis(char style) const;
    void input();  
    void output(); 
};
void CPoint::input(){
    cout << "Please enter point location: x y" << endl;
    cin >> x >> y;
}
void CPoint::output(){
    cout << "X of point is: " << x << endl << "Y of point is: " << y << endl; 
}
CPoint CPoint::SymmetricAxis(char style) const{
    CPoint p1;
    switch (style){
        case 'x':
            p1.y = -y;
            break;
        case 'y':
            p1.x = -x;
        case '0':
            p1.x = -x;
            p1.y = -y;
            break;
    }
    return p1;
}
int main(){
    CPoint p1, p2(1, 10), p3(1,10);
    p1.input();
    p1.output();
    p3 = p1.SymmetricAxis('0');
    p3.output();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SymmetricAxis` does *not* change the value of `p3`.  `SymmetricAxis` merely returns a new `CPoint` as an unnamed temporary value.  (That temporary value is initialized by the local variable `p1` in the body of `SymmetricAxis`.)

The copy-assignment operator copies this temporary value over the value of p3.

The `const` qualifier on `SymmetricAxis` only means that the call `p1.SymmetricAxis('0')` will not change `p1`.  It says nothing about what you assign the result of that call to.

<sub>(Implementation / optimization note:  The compiler is allowed to optimize away one or more of these copies, but the meaning of `const` in this context presumes these copies happen.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You're changing variables on a local inside the function, not any of the member variables. If you for example write `this->y = 0`, you will get a compile error. The `const` qualifier only promises not to change `*this`.

To clarify, `*this` refers to `p1` (which you call the function on.) You create a local variable also called `p1` which you are allowed to modify (because it's not the same `this`). `p3` does not come into play at all.